# Nobel prize Manabe's 1967 code for solving the 1D atmospheric thermal equilibrium model

Tags: atmosphere-modelling, reproducibility

Does someone know where to find a (hopefully modern) version of the numerical code for solving the **1D atmospheric thermal equilibrium model**, the one Syukuro Manabe & Richard T. Wetherald used in their seminal **1967** publication in *J.Atmosph.Sciences* ? ([doi:10.1175/1520-0469(1967)024<0241:TEOTAW>2.0.CO;2](https://doi.org/10.1175/1520-0469(1967)024%3C0241:TEOTAW%3E2.0.CO;2)). I guess with modern computers it's a matter of seconds to solve, and redo the calculations from their work, and I'ld be pleased to use this in my math for Earth sciences course, as an example (university, 2nd year).

Comment: Maybe try https://doi.org/10.1175/JCLI-D-18-0774.1 ?

Comment: The paper has 9 and 18 cells for the entire atmosphere in a static model.. you are definetly right when suspecting that it would take seconds (rather microseconds, my guess...) on modern computers..

Comment: Thanks @Jean-Marie-Prival, that's for sure a good reference to go on with the science. However concerning the numerical tool, the github repo shows an object oriented programming source, which is too much a black box for the use I want : okay for real use, but not for learning at a beginner's level (licence 2è année !). Cependant, encore merci pour la réf.